# Allowing Anyone to Run a Meteor app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, deployment, meteor

I am looking for advice on deploying a meteor app. I have put together an application that clients are going to install on their own networks. I have the development version working fine and am trying to determine a good way for them to deploy. I want the install to be as simple as possible. Some of them will have full on networks/administrators and others will just want to install on a local box.

In development, mongo is shipped with meteor and the user only has to run meteor to get it going. Is this not a good practice for a production level app?

The other (preferred option) is to deploy it as a node app. But this requires a separate mongo installation and just seems like an additional step to me.

The way I am thinking, If I shipped to the clients as is, the package.json could install everything needed, including meteor in one step.

I know there is something I am missing in this. Is the meteor mongo version not as stable as a standalone mongo installation? Or is there an easy way to build everything at once?

I was looking at Meteor-Up and that seemed like the perfect solution. But I was not able to get it going with localhost and It looks like this is not possible from some of the comments.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Kyle

Comment: I know this isn't an answer, but can't you just get them to run the couple of terminal commands needed to install and run meteor? You could make a screencast if it seems intimidating to them. And then if they need to run it online, just give them instructions to set up an account at digital ocean or whereever and deploy it.

Comment: Hmm - that is kind of what I was thinking along the lines of. But I was unsure if having a user run a live application through meteor would potentially not be a good idea. But if that can work for the less knowledgable user, it would make things easier on my end!

Comment: Are they always installing on a *nix box, or are they also maybe installing on Windows?  If *nix, there are plenty of ways to do it, easiest might be to simply write a shell script.  If Windows, you could do it as an installer.  If both, pick the easiest one for either platform.  As far as running in Dev mode, I would HIGHLY recommend not do that.  Some code, like plugins, can be set to only run in Dev mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you take a look at Docker containers and containerization for distribution. You can actually install the entire thing into a container (or, a set of containers), and then distribute those containers. Your users could run the containers in a number of ways. Locally, after installing docker rather simply, they could spin them up with one command. On a remote server, the installation would be just about the same. They could even use a service like AWS Elastic Beanstalk to get them started.

It would be completely cross platform, very simple, and you could control the installation process.